# Is this query possible? SELECT FROM 2 tables LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I know this will cause an ambiguous error since Name exists in both tables. But
I want to select the Name from these two tables. Name is a column in t_1 and t_2.  Is it possible to select from two tables? Is there a way for me to select the name between two tables, and returns a single column of data?

```
SELECT Name
FROM t_1, t_2
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`/`UNION`,

Comment: Thanks felix, the answers are all correct, but i'm gonna accept the 1st answer by William, just up vote on the others, since the gap is 47secs

Comment: There are a lot of answers suggesting either UNION or UNION ALL. Be aware that UNION only returns a distinct list and in order to produce this, SQL Server has to perform a distinct sort. This can often be far more expensive than UNION ALL. If you don't need the distinct sort you should not choose UNION over UNION ALL.

Comment: yes, i've already read their difference.. thanks sir @DatumPoint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try a `UNION`;

```
SELECT Name
FROM t_1
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
UNION
SELECT Name
FROM t_2
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
```

Note, `UNION ALL` can also be used, this will also return multiple instances of the same name if they exist. Use whichever satisfies your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name
   FROM t_1
   WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
UNION ALL
SELECT Name
   FROM t_2
   WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine using UNION

```
SELECT Name
FROM t_2
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
union 
SELECT Name
FROM t_2
WHERE Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can using **Aliasing**.

```
SELECT t1.Name AS 'NAME-T1', t2.Name AS 'NAME-T2'
FROM t_1 AS t1, t_2 AS t2
WHERE t1.Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%' OR t2.Name LIKE '%' + @USER + '%'
```